# How to find video adapter name with if-else statment use *.bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, wmic, win32-process

Can not figure out what is wrong, please help.

Main goal is look like this (pseudocode):

```
if(getCurrentVideoAdapterName().contains("List of video adapter names"))
{
print True
}else
{
print false
}
```

But this need to be done in *.bat file, I am a new in this and this is my trys:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET count=1
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* skip=1" %%F IN (`wmic PATH Win32_videocontroller GET description`) DO (
  SET var!count!=%%F
  SET /a count=!count!+1
)
ECHO %var1%
ECHO %var2%
Findstr /c:%var1% listNameVideoAdapters.txt 
ENDLOCAL
if %errorlevel%==0 (
echo "True")
if %errorlevel%==1 (
echo "Falsee!")
pause
```

`wmic PATH Win32_videocontroller GET description -return` returns:

```
Description
NVIDIA GeForce GT 720M
Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000
```

and `listNameVideoAdapters.txt` contains a list with different video card names (include my NVIDIA GeForce GT 720M )

Comment: Please provide the contents of your `listNameVideoAdapters.txt`. At the very least, please explain whether the items in the list are exact full strings, or part strings, for matching? Which format the file uses, _(layout and type information)_, and an indication of how many items are in that list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no need for a `for` loop:

```
wmic PATH Win32_videocontroller GET description |findstr /g:listNameVideoAdapters.txt >nul && echo True || echo False
```

`findstr /g` gets the list of strings to search from a file (which you already have)